# Do security concerns justify a DB design that adds multiple rows to a transaction table (1 per unit) for a SINGLE transaction for an INVENTORY system?

Tags: mysql, database, security, schema

**EDIT / UPDATE to question:**

The following question applies, specifically, to an INVENTORY application.

Specifically, the application supports a large number (thousands) of locations, each with a "medium" quantity of products (enough to fit on the shelves of a typical auto body shop).  However, the system *might* expand to support much larger warehouses.

I do not personally understand why an inventory application would be any different from any other large-scale database application, but the programmer I mention below has told me that in his experience, it is common for **inventory** applications to utilize the design discussed in this question.

The programmer also states that the design in question applies specifically for applications where there is a high theft rate; i.e. where people working in the auto body shops have an inclination to slip a few items of product here and there off the shelves.  Even in this scenario, I do not understand why having the **backend** system designed as indicated in this question (with the user interface unchanged) would warrant the design indicated.

Therefore, an addendum to the question below is **is the design discussed below appropriate specifically for an INVENTORY application in which the theft rate of shelf stockers on the floor is high**?

---

I had a significant difference of opinion with another programmer who presented a fundamentally different schema design proposal for an inventory database that is being built from scratch.

I would like to know whether the schema concept presented is either a standard design, and/or whether it should be considered the design of choice, or at least on par with other potential designs of choice, for an inventory system.

The inventory system is rather simple conceptually, consisting mostly of paint and other liquids, as well as some solid parts, that are stocked on the shelves of auto body shops throughout the country.  The items are delivered by truck, entered into the system as additions to the inventory, and then removed from the inventory in order to fulfill repair orders.

The programmer presented a design in which the transaction table (which records every time any inventory items are added to, or removed from, the shop's inventory) has **multiple rows** added to the table for every **individual** transaction, one per unit of quantity in the transaction.

For example, if a truck driver delivers 10 cans of a particular blue paint to the shop, and these 10 cans are entered into the system via a *single* transaction, that nonetheless *10* rows would be added to the transaction table, one per can of paint; each row would be absolutely identical except for the auto-incrementing primary key.

Specifically:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
  `transaction_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `part_id` int(10) unsigned, -- FK. parts.part_id
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned, -- FK: users.user_id
  `action` enum('ADD','REMOVE'),
  `action_date` datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_id`)
);
```

Notice, in particular, that the transaction table does **not** have a `quantity` column (in case, say, 10 cans of paint were added in one transaction).  Instead, there will be 10 rows added to this table for this single transaction (all with the `ADD` flag set).

From an ease of use, data size, programmatic complexity, and performance perspective, I have confidence that this design is distinctly not as good as a design that has a `quantity` column and only one row per transaction.  In this example, there would be only a *single* row added, and the `quantity` column would be set to `10`.

The justification given by the programmer is **security** against malicious users of various sorts.

He agrees that this design is a relatively small additional layer of security in addition to other typical security precautions, but he points out various sorts of potential security features of the *one row per unit quantity* approach.

In particular, it is easier to take advantage of granular database permissions to prevent malicious users who have hacked into the system (or who are internal employees with access to the system at some level) from deleting entire rows or making bulk row changes, than it is to prevent malicious users from modifying a single `quantity` field in a single row of data.

**In other words, the concept is "write once, freeze in stone, one row for every item".**

I did point out that the "write once, freeze in stone" concept also applies to the approach with a `quantity` column, but it is true that all a malicious user needs to do to "rewrite history" in the latter case is modify a single field in a single row to make significant changes; whereas the only way to make significant changes in the proposed system above is to either delete many rows or make changes to rows in bulk.

I note that from a programmatic perspective, the two designs are quite different.  The code to handle the *multiple rows per transaction* approach will be more complex, to a certain extent, than the code to handle the *single row per transaction* approach.

The programmer also pointed out that the very fact of the added code complexity using his suggested approach would make it *less likely* that a programmer in the future would make a mistake that could cause a major inaccuracy to appear in the data.  In response, I pointed out that the opposite also holds true: a programmer could more easily make an off-by-one error with his more complex design that could go undetected for many transactions, causing a potentially equally significant inaccuracy to appear in the data.

It does seem to me that any way you cut it, slice it, or dice it, there will be noticeably more complex coding logic to handle the programmatic interface to this proposed design, and there will be noticeably more overhead in terms of performance and scaling.  In other words, it's a fundamentally different database design approach, whose only justification is **security**.

(It's my sense that these security arguments applied much more strongly about 20 years ago, when the overall level of security for web applications and servers was much less sophisticated than it is today.  I have the sense that there's only a 1% security gain, at the cost of 30% overhead in programmer time and server scaling costs.)

My question is this: Should the design described here be seriously considered for this system?  Or is it clearly true that the schema design with only a single row per transaction - and a `quantity` column - is a better choice?

---

**ADDITIONAL COMMENT RELATED TO EDIT OF QUESTION AT TOP**:

I do not understand how the design discussed in this question would assist with security against gaming the system by **employees who stock (and remove items from) the shelves**, given that the USER INTERFACE of the application remains unchanged.

Am I missing an important detail about security design?  Is there some way in which the **backend** design discussed in this question would make it more difficult for shelf-stockers to game the system?

Alternatively, is there some business reason why **administrators** of the system who have access to the backend systems with **varying levels of user permission** would also have an inducement to game the system in such a way that the given design approach is warranted?

I'm really scratching my head over this one.

Comment: So I can reduce the likelihood of getting mugged by going to the bank to deposit each individual dollar I earn rather than depositing them all at once?

Comment: Interesting. 50 tons can be stored as 50.000.000 rows, each row per 1 milligram. We can also consider micrograms: 50 tons = 50.000.000.000 rows, one per each microgram - the security should be 1000 times stronger. When a customer asks me "why this simple report runs forever?" I will tell him: "we must count billion rows, this is a cost of a very strong security".

Comment: @kordirko The parts in this database each have a standard (reasonable) unit of measure, so this is the basis for each row.  I still have not clarified with the client what a "typical" number of items per transaction will be - and I do not believe the client is very certain about that, as the system might expand to new product lines in the future.  Until this programmer suggested the system he did, I had not concerned myself much with the question of typical quantities.  Paint cans are one major current product.

Comment: It is worth noting that the programmer told me that "inventory systems routinely are designed in this way".  I have worked with many complex databases over many years, and I have never seen a large-scale database designed in this way (although I *have* seen databases with the "write once, freeze forever" approach) - but I have not worked specifically with an **inventory** database in the past, so who am I to say?